# Rails Adding Twilio Sub Accounts : Uninitialized constant User::Twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

*********UPDATE : I just tried restarting the Rails server, and it seemed to have worked!

I've built a basic authentication system following Michael Hartl's tutorial on Rails, and now what I would like to do is to use Twilio's API to create a Twilio Sub Account when a user registers.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts

My thoughts on how to create it were to use a before_save in the User Model, and have twilio create the  Auth Token and Account Sid for the sub account. The problem is, that when I hit submit, I get --

```
NameError in UsersController#create

uninitialized constant User::Twilio
Rails.root: C:/Sites/dentist

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:45:in `create_twilio_subaccount'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

Here's my Current User Model :

```
#Twilio authentication credentials
ACCOUNT_SID = '####removed for stackoverflow#####'
ACCOUNT_TOKEN = '####removed for stackoverflow#####'


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  name               :string(255)
#  email              :string(255)
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null
#  password_digest    :string(255)
#  remember_token     :string(255)
#  twilio_account_sid :string(255)
#  twilio_auth_token  :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token
  before_save :create_twilio_subaccount

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true


    private

      def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end

    def create_twilio_subaccount     
      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
      @subaccount = @client.accounts.create({:FriendlyName => self[:email]})
      self.twilio_account_sid = @subaccount.sid
      self.twilio_auth_token  = @subaccount.auth_token
    end

end
```

Any help on what I should do inside create_twilio_subaccount would be greatly appreciated it. This is just my guess at how to do it, based on how the remember_token worked. Let me know if I'm doing something completely wacky!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried restarting the Rails server, and it seemed to have worked!