# Creating generators Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

I am having a problem creating a generator in rails this is the error I am getting. 
I am trying to create a generator that creates does SMS verification through the provider Twilio.

```
require "sms_auth-twilio"
NameError: uninitialized constant Twilio::Rails
from /Users/sherodtaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sms_auth-twilio-0.0.2/lib/sms_auth-twilio.rb:3:in `<module:Twilio>'
from /Users/sherodtaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sms_auth-twilio-0.0.2/lib/sms_auth-twilio.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sherodtaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /Users/sherodtaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/sherodtaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from (irb):1
from /Users/sherodtaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

This is my code

```
 require "sms_auth-twilio/version"
   module Twilio
     class TwilioGenerator < Rails::Generator::Base
     source_root File.expand_path("../generator", __FILE__)
     def add_twilio_initializer
       copy_file "twilio.rb", "config/initializer/twilio.rb"
     end
     # config info for the API
     def twilio_config_info
       copy_file "twilio.yml", "config/twilio.yml"
     end
     # Verification Controller to verify the company
     def copy_verifications 
       copy_file "verifications_controller", "app/contoller/verifications_controller.rb"
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Is the error you show from running the generator?

Comment: Yeah Idk if its my code or what because I wrapped it in a gem. Maybe thats why?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your Rails server and then try

For your Help see this link : [Rails Adding Twilio Sub Accounts : Uninitialized constant User::Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685557/rails-adding-twilio-sub-accounts-uninitialized-constant-usertwilio)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but this is not typically how I see generators created within a gem.  Usually they are separate from the actual `gem_name.rb` file.  I think if you move the generator logic into the more common `lib/generators/generator_name/generator_name.rb` you'll have more luck. And then you can place the files to be copied within a subdir `../generator_name/templates/`

Also note you need to add the .rb ending to your `copy_file "verifications_controller,"`

For a template to work off, you can follow the layout of a simple gem I wrote [here](https://github.com/joofsh/joofaq) which utilizes a generator.